# Codeigniter, The requested document was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've developed a web site using codeigniter; actually it works on localhost also it works on  `http://site-name/controller for example.`

However when I changed the domain to `domain.com/site-name/controller`. I've got a **Not Found page** because The requested document was not found on this server.

htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: is the `$config['base_url']`set correctly in `application/config/config.php` ?

Comment: it is empty .. $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: you should put your new domain there like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain.com/site-name/';` it has to be pointing to the root where your whole application is

Comment: i did what you advise but nothing change !!

Comment: do you have any `.htaccess` file in the root folder?

Comment: ya,
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your rewrite to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site-name/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

So that your `site-name` folder is included in the rewrite, otherwise your rewrite will look in the root folder of the domain for the `index.php`